# How to define initial values for ModelForm rightly?

Tags: django, django-models

I have no idea and I need to ask your advice.

I have simple form:

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text','author','news']
```

I want to add form in DetailView and hadle this form there:

```
class NewsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'news/detail.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        return {'news': self.get_object(), 'author': self.request.user}

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NewsDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CommentForm(initial=self.get_initial())
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.save()
```

I don't want to show 'author' and news fieds. But if I hide them I can't to get initial values..

UPDATED:

After form validation I need return current form instance in the template through updating page. I attempted the next:

```
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST, request=request)
        if comment_form.is_valid() and comment_form.validate_user():
            comment_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
        else:
            context = super(NewsDetailView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form'] = comment_form
            return self.render_to_response(context)
```

But did not work.

Comment: How are you hiding them?

Comment: I tried not show them. Just used {{ form.text }} in the template.

Comment: You can show them in your template if you have a `HiddenInput`

Comment: Should I necessarly show 'author' and 'news' fields even I did them HiddenInput? I thoght exists other way.

Comment: If you don't render them the form will only submit the input from the `text` field, and that will end as an invalid form since you are defining `fields = ['text','author','news']` in the `Meta` class of your form.

Comment: I found in this big vulnerability, I can change value in hiden input filed and leave comment on behalf of other user. How could I save form without defining author in form? Maybe get author value from `request.USER`? I don't know how to add new comment without defining 'author' in the form

Comment: You need to validate if the ID of the user in your form is the same as the `request.user`. Check [Cleaning a specific field attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

Comment: One more question, If possible) how can I return form errors to the page? according to my code `            comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST, request=request)
            if comment_form.is_valid() and comment_form.validate_user():
                comment_form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
            else:
                kwargs['from'] = CommentForm()
                return super(NewsDetailView,self).get(self,request,*args,**kwargs)`

Comment: Can you please update your question with this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't render your fields using `{{ form.author }}` and `{{ form.news }}` the form won't validate. Try using a `HiddenInput` for each field, You can do that by overriding the `__init__` method of your form:

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['author'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields['news'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text','author','news']
```